# how to replace part a file with a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a .msh file which can be opened and modified by text readers. I want to open it in python, then replace some specific rows with a numpy array and save it as a new .msh file. My numpy array has 9 columns and hundreds of rows. My file has also hundreds of rows. I want to replace the rows of my file that have 9 columns with my numpy array. For sure, the number of rows in my numpy array is the same as number rows that have 9 columns in my file. For simplicity I showed here only two rows but in reality I have hundreds of rows.
The numpy array is:

```
arr_1= np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                 [-1, 0, 0, 1, 46, 2, -11, 0, 0]])
```

my file (my_file) is as following:

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$Nodes
2929
1 26.66002035140991 0.75 1.25
-1 5 14 13.2 7.4444 11 9 -3 0.15 
0.2 9 54.45 1 63 22.45 0 12 425.65
```

Then, I want to get a new saved file with a new name as:

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$Nodes
2929
1 26.66002035140991 0.75 1.25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
-1 0 0 1 46 2 -11 0 0
```

I only could do the following but it was not working:

```
with open('my_file') as f:
   new_data= line.split() for line in f if len(line.split()) == 9
   for i in new_data:
        for j in arr_1:
             i = j
```

I tried it but it was not successful at all. So, I appreciate any hint and help.
Cheers,
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, in which a new file named `changed` will be written. In order to reduce disk writes (to improve the performance, especially for large files), chunks of lines will be written to the new file.

```
chunk_size = 3
buffer = ""
i = 0
# the index of lines with 9 digits 
relavent_line = 0

with open('changed', 'a') as fout:
    with open('original', 'r') as fin:
        
        for line in fin:
            
            if len(line.split()) == 9:
                aux_string = ' '.join([str(num) for num in arr_1[relavent_line]])
                buffer += '%s\n' % aux_string
                relavent_line += 1
            else:
                buffer += line 
                
            i+=1
            if i == chunk_size:
                fout.write(buffer)
                i=0
                buffer = ""
              
    # make sure all lines will be written to the output file   
    if buffer:
        fout.write(buffer)
        i=0
        buffer = ""
```

Comment: Dear @meTchaikovsky, your solution is fantastic. It is exactly what I was looking. Just one note, Is there any way to embed in for loop? lets say, I have a series of original files and also a series of arr_1s. How can I make a series of changed files for them?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
with open('my_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        new_data = line.split()
        if len(new_data)==9:
            for i in new_data:
                for j in arr_1:
                    i = j
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that adding some explanations usually improves answers.

Comment: Dear @Mobi1968, I really appreciate your solution. Have you any idea how I can save a new file? Now, it is only running some for and if loops. In fact, I want to save it as a new .msh file. Meanwhile, I appreciate any more efficient solution. As I said my real data have hundreds and in cases thousands of rows e.g. I took 11min 28s to run it for my real data.